# metro style UI is too early or not

Tags: website-design, gui-design, html, css, metro

I think **metro style UI** is just beautiful and user friendly. It is suitable for both Tablet and PC.
Should I make my new website design in metro style or conventional standard?

Comment: Hi @Sandeep I'm afraid that this is far too generic a question, we can't answer this unless you are able to be more specific with your question. Have a look at [what makes a good question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#what-makes-a-good-question) from our FAQ and see if you can amend your request to better fit the Q&A format.

Comment: Sandeep, what kind of website is it? What problem are you trying to solve? How can we help you decide what to do?

Comment: i have to make new website design.i think i have to use metro style.i m confusing , my user will accept this design or not relative to user friendly.

Comment: @Rahul: I don't think there's a problem. It sounds like Sandeep is looking for opinions on whether it makes sense to copy Metro's look-and-feel for a website he's designing.

Comment: hmm.not problem.asking opinion.

Comment: The Q & A format of this site isn't set up for asking opinions, though once you earn the [privilege to chat](http://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat) (you need 20 rep/a few upvotes) you can ask stuff like this in Chat though, as it's more free-form discussion

Comment: Interesting UX question.  The site is perfectly well suited to answer (In my opinion), but because people close the question, we can't.  I voted to reopen, but not enough people do that.  SHort answer for you:  It isn't too early.  You could absolutely go for it.  It's an interesting UI metaphor for a website.  If you want to really take it further, make it work on Mobile like the Windows Phone.

Comment: this is not Q & A site.this knowledge exchange site.User Get answer about their confusion.

Comment: @sandeep - no, this actually IS a Q&A site. It's in the very first line of the ["About" page](http://ux.stackexchange.com/about). Check out [the FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on valid questions to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what aspects of Metro you're talking about. If you want to emulate what they've been calling their "authentically digital" aesthetic of clean lines and squares, go for it.

There would be two thigns I'd warn against using though.

1. The hidden charms. In Metro/Windows8 you slide in from the top, bottom, and sides to reveal core functionality like switching pages, revealing tools, apps, etc. As an OS, you can expect that your users will figure this kind of thing out, but I feel that would be too great an expectation for a website that could be visited by anyone on any device.
2. The horizontal scrolling. Horizontal scrolling feels natural and efficient on touch devices, but is a big pain for people using Keyboard and Mouse.

Comment: thats i need.thanx andrew